# Breeze EntityManger executeQuery spans february dates by a month i.e. march

Tags: breeze

Breeze EntityManger executeQuery spans february dates by a month i.e. march.This happens only when system date on which browser is running is set to 30th of any month.

**Say its 3**0th of April 2017** as date of my machine**.
I have **22-feb-2017** as ReviewDate in my database.
When i run below statement:

```
var eq = breeze.EntityQuery
         .from("Reviews")
          .where("ReviewId", "==", "a0544246-bb38-46ff-ba0c-eef16a135378");
em.executeQuery(eq)
        .then(function (data) {
        data.results[0].ReviewDate // Gets output as **22-march-2017**
```

Comment: What does the data look like coming from the server, in the http response?

Comment: ReviewAltId
:
9
ReviewGoals
:
[]
ReviewId
:
"7e95f67e-0172-4e2d-811e-c9415c3508bc"
ReviewServiceDeliveryCodes
:
[]
StartDate
:
"2017-02-01T00:00:00.000"
Status
:
null
StatusId
:
"74265756-6322-4411-9977-42e57068d413"
StopDate
:
"2017-02-28T00:00:00.000"

Comment: Above result is from network tab but when breeze EntityManger executeQuery processes StartDate : "2017-02-01T00:00:00.000" it changes it to 1st March 2017